# how to change the default color of string during drawRect (), core graphic

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, drawrect

I am drawing a string in rectangle using following method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    .................................................
    .................................................
    for(NSString *titleString in self.titlesArray) {
        CGContextSaveGState(context);                                                 // Pushes a copy of the current graphics state onto the graphics state stack for the context.
        CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake((self.segmentWidth*i), yCoor, self.segmentWidth, self.font.pointSize);
        CGContextAddRect(context, labelRect);                                         // Adds a rectangular path to the current path.
        [titleString drawInRect:labelRect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeClip alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }
}
```

The outcome is

[image]

As we can see the default color for the string is in black

***Question*** : Is that possible to change the color of string during drawRect() and how can I archive it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
[[UIColor blueColor] set];
```

will work. If you want all of the strings to be the same, put this before the loop.

Comment: Thanks just tried it and worked like charm. However, as it is indicated from Apple is : `Sets the color of subsequent stroke and fill operations to the color that the receiver represents.` I dont know why it works because i think this method is used to set the color for `stroke` and `operation`.... ( not text al all ).. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. UIColor set sets the stroke and fill color. The text is drawn with the stroke and fill colors. You stated it worked. What's the confusion?

Comment: Ohhhh I think what I am missing is text is actually a set of strokes and [UIColor set] is used to fill color for these stroke which means text...Is it correct, sir ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Don't forget to make an answer correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
```